# Deleting an Auth Firebase User When an Activity Is Destroyed

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an activity called ValidadorActivity, in this activity I do a sms validation, right after the user signs up.

The registration is done by the Firebase Auth but it is done before this validation, so I look for a way to delete the auth firebase registry when the user exits the validation screen without putting the Token that was sent by sms correctly.

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        //Ao fechar completamente a tela de validação com o campo textValidacao nulo ou incorreto, o cadastro no autenticacao e no banco de dados sao apagados, para evitar o cadastro de usuarios não validados.

        String codigoDigitado = codigoValidacao.getText().toString(); //Pega o texto da caixa de texto

        if (! codigoDigitado.equals(tokenGerado)) {//Verifica se esse texto e igual

            user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() { //deleta o usuario no Auth
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {//Testa para ver se funcionou

                        Log.i("Usuario deletado(auth)","Sim");


                    }else{

                        Log.i("Usuario deletado(auth)","Não");

                    }

                }
            });
}
```

This code is not running, I think the code is right. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: If you think the code is correct, what happens if you run it in a debugger? If you put a breakpoint on `String codigoDigitado...` does it get hit? If you step through the code from there, what line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I checked through a Log, and when I close the activity it is not even going through the onDestroy method.

Comment: That makes sense, since `onDestroy` only runs when the activity is destroyed by the system, which usually is not when it is closed by the user. You might want to look at `onPause` or `onStop`, and in general have a look at the Android activity lifecycle: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: Wow ok, i will look. Thank u!

Comment: I tested your suggestion but it does not work the way I would like it, I want the user to be able to pause or stop the activity and only when leaving it for another activity, turn the code!

Comment: So I thought about onDestroy, actually I'm looking for an event similar to onClose

Comment: There is no `onClose`. The activity diagram contains the only options available.

Comment: Yes, I know but I am looking for a similar to onClose

Answer (score 1):

The `onDestroy` method only runs when the activity is destroyed by the system, which is seldom the same as when the user exits the activity.

You might want to look at `onPause` or `onStop`, and in general have a look at the [Android activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) for when precisely you want the code to run.